# Java- TitledBorder in gridbag layout expanding as the window expands

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout, titled-border

I am making a form using the `GridBag` layout which has a titled border. The first `TitledBorder` `panel` which is Customer Details works fine except that I would like to know how add some spacing between the first title and `textfield`(eg first name) and the following title and `textfield`(eg last name) below it.

The problem with the second `panel` which is Room Details is that it expands as I enlarge/expand the window and as this happens, the components inside it also shift. I would like it to remain fixed like the components in the first `panel`.

This is the form.java class:

```
public class form extends JFrame{


JPanel pnl= new JPanel();
JPanel pnl1= new JPanel();
JLabel fname= new JLabel("First name: ");
JLabel lname= new JLabel("Last name: ");
JLabel contact= new JLabel("Contact number: ");
JLabel email= new JLabel("Email address: ");
JLabel address= new JLabel("Address: ");
JLabel numpsns= new JLabel("Number of persons: ");
JTextField fnameField= new JTextField(25);
JTextField lnameField= new JTextField(25);
JTextField contactField= new JTextField(25);
JTextField emailField= new JTextField(25);
JTextArea txtadd= new JTextArea(5, 25);

SpinnerModel sm= new SpinnerNumberModel(1,0,30,1);
JSpinner spinner= new JSpinner(sm);

public form(){

    this.setTitle("Reservation Form");


    pnl.setBorder(new TitledBorder(null,"Customer Details", TitledBorder.CENTER, TitledBorder.TOP, null, null));
    getContentPane().add(pnl, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    pnl.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gc= new GridBagConstraints();

    //first column of the grid//
    gc.anchor= GridBagConstraints.EAST;
    gc.weightx=0.5;
    gc.weighty=0.5;

    gc.gridx=0;
    gc.gridy=0;

    pnl.add(fname, gc);

    gc.gridx=0;
    gc.gridy=1;
    pnl.add(lname,gc);

    gc.gridx=0;
    gc.gridy=2;
    pnl.add(contact, gc);

    gc.gridx=0;
    gc.gridy=3;
    pnl.add(email, gc);

    gc.gridx=0;
    gc.gridy=4;
    pnl.add(address, gc);

    //second column//
    gc.anchor= GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    gc.gridx=1;
    gc.gridy= 0;
    pnl.add(fnameField,gc);

    gc.gridx=1;
    gc.gridy=1;
    pnl.add(lnameField, gc);

    gc.gridx=1;
    gc.gridy=2;
    pnl.add(contactField, gc);

    gc.gridx=1;
    gc.gridy=3;
    pnl.add(emailField, gc);

    gc.gridx=1;
    gc.gridy=4;
    pnl.add(txtadd, gc);

    //second Titled Border//        

    pnl1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "Booking Details", TitledBorder.CENTER, TitledBorder.CENTER));

    add(pnl1, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    pnl1.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gc1= new GridBagConstraints();


    //first column//

    gc1.weightx= 0.5;
    gc1.weighty=0.5;

    gc1.gridx=0;
    gc1.gridy=0;

    pnl1.add(numpsns, gc1);

    gc1.anchor= GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    gc1.gridx=1;
    gc1.gridy= 0;
    pnl1.add(spinner,gc1);




       }

 }
```

**form_main.java class**

```
public class form_main {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

    form form_display= new form();
     form_display.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
     form_display.pack();
     form_display.setSize(500,280);
     form_display.setVisible(true);

    }

 }
```

Here is a screenshot of how it is:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've added the second panel to the `CENTRE` position of a `BorderLayout`, this is the expected behaviour for this type of layout. Perhaps you should use another `GridBagLayout` to layout the two panels

To add internal spacing to the panel you could use a `CompoundLayout`, wrapping the `TitledBorder` and an `EmptyBorder` together or set the `GridBagConstraints#insets` property

## Simple example...

[image: Simple]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SpinnerModel;
import javax.swing.SpinnerNumberModel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.border.CompoundBorder;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

public class Form extends JFrame {

    JPanel pnl = new JPanel();
    JPanel pnl1 = new JPanel();
    JLabel fname = new JLabel("First name: ");
    JLabel lname = new JLabel("Last name: ");
    JLabel contact = new JLabel("Contact number: ");
    JLabel email = new JLabel("Email address: ");
    JLabel address = new JLabel("Address: ");
    JLabel numpsns = new JLabel("Number of persons: ");
    JTextField fnameField = new JTextField(25);
    JTextField lnameField = new JTextField(25);
    JTextField contactField = new JTextField(25);
    JTextField emailField = new JTextField(25);
    JTextArea txtadd = new JTextArea(5, 25);

    SpinnerModel sm = new SpinnerNumberModel(1, 0, 30, 1);
    JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(sm);

    public Form() {

        this.setTitle("Reservation Form");
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        gbc.fill = gbc.HORIZONTAL;

        Border border = new CompoundBorder(
                new TitledBorder(null, "Customer Details", TitledBorder.CENTER, TitledBorder.TOP, null, null),
                new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));

        pnl.setBorder(border);
        getContentPane().add(pnl, gbc);

        pnl.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();

        //first column of the grid//
        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        gc.weightx = 0.5;
        gc.weighty = 0.5;

        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 0;

        pnl.add(fname, gc);

        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 1;
        pnl.add(lname, gc);

        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 2;
        pnl.add(contact, gc);

        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 3;
        pnl.add(email, gc);

        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 4;
        pnl.add(address, gc);

        //second column//
        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        gc.gridx = 1;
        gc.gridy = 0;
        pnl.add(fnameField, gc);

        gc.gridx = 1;
        gc.gridy = 1;
        pnl.add(lnameField, gc);

        gc.gridx = 1;
        gc.gridy = 2;
        pnl.add(contactField, gc);

        gc.gridx = 1;
        gc.gridy = 3;
        pnl.add(emailField, gc);

        gc.gridx = 1;
        gc.gridy = 4;
        pnl.add(txtadd, gc);

        //second Titled Border//        
        pnl1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "Booking Details", TitledBorder.CENTER, TitledBorder.CENTER));

        add(pnl1, gbc);

        pnl1.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gc1 = new GridBagConstraints();

        //first column//
        gc1.weightx = 0.5;
        gc1.weighty = 0.5;

        gc1.gridx = 0;
        gc1.gridy = 0;

        pnl1.add(numpsns, gc1);

        gc1.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        gc1.gridx = 1;
        gc1.gridy = 0;
        pnl1.add(spinner, gc1);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                Form frame = new Form();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

> Thanks a lot. Can you show me how I can change the font and size of the titles(like Customer Details, Booking Details) of the borders? Font.BOLD doesn't seem to work in createTitledBorder

...

> `new TitledBorder(null, "Customer Details", TitledBorder.CENTER, TitledBorder.TOP, UIManager.getFont("Label.font").deriveFont(Font.BOLD), null);`

...

> That didn't work

Works fine for me...

[image: TitledBorder]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
            p1.setBorder(new TitledBorder(null, "Customer Details", TitledBorder.CENTER, TitledBorder.TOP, null, null));
            JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
            p2.setBorder(new TitledBorder(null, "Customer Details", TitledBorder.CENTER, TitledBorder.TOP, UIManager.getFont("Label.font").deriveFont(Font.BOLD), null));
            JPanel p3 = new JPanel();
            p3.setBorder(new TitledBorder(null, "Customer Details", TitledBorder.CENTER, TitledBorder.TOP, UIManager.getFont("Label.font").deriveFont(Font.ITALIC), null));
            JPanel p4 = new JPanel();
            p4.setBorder(new TitledBorder(null, "Customer Details", TitledBorder.CENTER, TitledBorder.TOP, UIManager.getFont("Label.font").deriveFont(Font.BOLD | Font.ITALIC), null));

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.weighty = 1;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

            add(p1, gbc);
            add(p2, gbc);
            add(p3, gbc);
            add(p4, gbc);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show how I am supposed to add another `GridBagLayout` to layout the two panels?

Comment: Set the layout of the frame to GrudBagLayout

Comment: I tried `this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());` after the `this.setTitle("Reservation Form");` line and it threw an exception

Comment: It likely threw an exception because you're still using the `BorderLayout` constraints (`BorderLayout.NORTH`)  instead of using `GridBagConstraints`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you show me how I can change the font and size of the titles(like Customer Details, Booking Details) of the borders? `Font.BOLD` doesn't seem to work in `createTitledBorder`

Comment: `new TitledBorder(null, "Customer Details", TitledBorder.CENTER, TitledBorder.TOP, UIManager.getFont("Label.font").deriveFont(Font.BOLD), null);`

Comment: Yes, it is working fine now. Maybe I did some mistake somewhere. Thanks a lot for your help:) Happy Coding!